# Why a class does need to implement an interface?

Tags: c#, oop

Soon I was writing code in .net framework, I needed a method but can't access that. After a search I have learnt to implement an interface first. I know that interfaces provide differentiation or polymorphism (i think). But why did .net framework want me to implement that interface? Why is it necessary?

That was a generic handler that needs IReadOnlySessionState,IRequiresSessionState interfaces for Session usage.

Comment: Becasue. Because whoever designed this part of the framework like that decided that this is how he makes it. This is how it was designed.

Comment: Because an interface is a contract. If you want your class to be used as a Session object, it must respect that contract thus implement the interface.

Comment: .net framework just wants to waste our time so it makes up interfaces we have to implement. I just close the IDE

Comment: Weyland, I just want to learn it exactly. Not complaining about that

Answer (score 1):

As TomTom said, because it was designed that way... why was it designed that way? here's the most likely answer, the answer why Interfaces are so usefull.

Taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx)

"An interface contains definitions for a group of related functionalities that a class or a struct can implement.

By using interfaces, you can, for example, include behavior from multiple sources in a class. That capability is important in C# because the language doesn't support multiple inheritance of classes. In addition, you must use an interface if you want to simulate inheritance for structs, because they can't actually inherit from another struct or class."

In your case you are implementing multiple interfaces.

As for Polymorphism...

"A base class can also implement interface members by using virtual members. In that case, a derived class can change the interface behavior by overriding the virtual members. For more information about virtual members, see Polymorphism."

Comment: In my example, generic handler needs an interface, but an interface or an abstract class method doesn't contain any alghoritm. Just we override it. So in my example, where does .net fw get the needed alghoritm of empty methods?

Comment: It is needed as far as the interface / contract is concerned... if your code does not call a method then the method does not need an implementation, just the signature will satisfy the interface.